# How is 1 bit transfered from RAM to a 1 bit register?

Tags: transistors, memory, ram, dram

I've been reading on computer RAM and CPUs. I came to the conclusion that most RAM today use arrays of DRAM while CPU registers and caches use SRAM. 1 bit DRAM is a circuit with one capacitor and 1 transistor which controls the flow of charge in and out of the capacitor.

When the transfer from RAM occurs the CPU places the address required on the address bus and the RAM controller "opens" the transistors of the bits specified by the address.

If containing a charge, the capacitor will then discharge onto the data bus to the capacitor of the 1 bit register.

My question is about the requirements of the register state when the transfer occurs. If the bit of the register is set, then even if the RAM capacitor contains a charge, it will not discharge onto the data bus. The operation is thus not necessary.

Another situation is one where the register is set while the RAM bit is not set. If the path is open between the 2 capacitors then the charge will be transfered from the register to RAM which is not the required behavior.

I think of it as with the following circuit:

[image]

Is it the right way to think about memory transfers in computers?

Is the register grounded to 0 before the transfer occurs?

Comment: Didn't read the question, but your PSU is shorted.

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you edit the question with the actual correct circuit

Comment: This diagram is totally wrong and not the right way to think about "memory transfers". Learn about logic gates.

Comment: @user253751 I know this isn't the right circuit. I wanted the correct circuit without short circuit that does what my example does without modification. Should I just add a resistance to avoid the short circuit?

Comment: @user123 You should learn about logic gates and try building some circuits with logic gates. I recommend Logisim or one of its forks.

Comment: @user253751 I know about logic gates. :/

Comment: Have you tried making a circuit with logic gates?

Comment: My question is more complex than that. It's not about logic gates. My circuit is a simplification of a DRAM to register circuit. I know there is some logic in between. Truth is nobody clearly answered the question and most often when nobody does means nobody can.

Answer (score 4):

The situation is far more complex than this. The DRAM has sense amplifiers and bus drivers that provide a strong logic level output signal. There are also several layers of logic between the DRAM output and the 1-bit register. A full answer would be quite broad and lengthy, but you should start by studying computer architecture.

Comment: But at some point the charge will be amplified and transferred onto the data bus. Logic in between is important but if you have a simple processor built on a breadboard then is it the right way to implement memory? I heard of some students building an 8 bits processor. How do these students go about building RAM memory?

Comment: I suspect that the simplest way to implement RAM on a breadboard is to buy a static RAM chip and plug it in.

Comment: In which book or resource is this topic covered? Maybe you can consider adding that to your answer?

Comment: @ShashankVM One could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory and the references listed therein.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the right way to think about memory transfers in computers?

no. In no data bus I can think of, a data-storing capacitor would be discharged directly to the bus to drive it - I mean, that would mean that each of the RAM cells would have to store an *incredible* amount of energy, just to "swing around" the bus.

Instead, there's always a readout or sense amplifier. Whether there is one per cell, or one for the selected line, depends on the technology (with modern memories, you practically have to have the amplifier extremely close to your data-carrying capacity).

That reads out the bit, amplifies it, sends it down a long line of logic. At the end of that stands a bus driver, and that's what's finally driving the bus.

There's *never* a direct electrical path between any processor part and the memory cell. That wouldn't even work – electricity can't flow fast enough. (Your PC CPU might be clocking at 4 GHz. In the time of a single clock cycle, you can't even bring an electromagnetic wave the distance from a CPU to the memory. Speed of light is a natural limit.)

Comment: I guess you are right since you seem to know more than I do. But when will the data actually be transfered. I think that memory read is a few clock cycles. Is the memory temporarily stored in a data buffer in the RAM controller? Otherwise the charge of the capacitor, even though amplified, will have to be transfered to the register at some point.

Comment: there's multiple stages at which things are stored intermediately. There's no "charge" transfer on the memory bus of a modern computer; that's already fast enough that you should be thinking of the bus-driving end as something emitting an RF signal into a transmission line, and the receiving and as actually something that has to receive. Really, **so** many layers between your transistor storing the bit and the register in the CPU, they aren't even remotely coupled.

Comment: I doubt there is "multiple stages" where things are stored intermediately. That would slow down a lot the RAM and be expensive. Processors and RAM aren't using radio waves they don't have receivers and transmitters. The instruction needs to be done before the next instruction since it could rely on the register content.

Comment: @user123 you're plainly wrong. Nothing in this needs to be done in one cycle, there's multiple stages because it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: I know there are multiple stages but I doubt data is stored intermediately at these stages. I found a pretty nice book on this subject. I'm gonna read it eventually. https://www.amazon.com/CMOS-Memory-Circuits-Tegze-Haraszti/dp/0792379500 or a downloadable version: https://b-ok.cc/book/461479/92e467?redirect=32853093

Comment: @user123 yeah, nice book about the storage technology. You're still wrong. That book is about how the bits are stored in CMOS memory ICs, and read out on the chip itself, and doesn't concert itself *at all* with how the data gets from the memory chip to its destination, the CPU. There's multiple layers of things you're just ignoring.

Comment: If you know about it then write an answer with some details and some good books/links and I'll mark it as accepted. When you say there's a bus driver is that software or some kind of microcode. We're looking at hardware. Hardware isn't intelligent and really works with electric currents, moving charges. There is no way for the hardware to know what is the content of memory without storing a charge and "reading" that charge back. Since, like I said, I doubt that data is stored intermediately, then a path must be open at some point between the data bus and the register to read the data.

Comment: A *driver* isn't software here. It's something that *drives some sort of load or line*, electrically. "Driver" being a term in operating systems comes from the electrical concept. (which comes from a mechanical concept in turn, and predates your meaning of the word driver by maybe 100 years?)

Comment: and really, "a path must be open": is it really hard to imagine that, maybe, you're just wrong? Again, you seem to be missing the bigger picture here and that within the time of one DDR edge, charge can't even travel far enough due to you know, speed of light being a hard upper limit.

Comment: As to what I read, the memory controller is now integrated in the CPU. It sends a read command to the memory and then WaitState until the memory asserts a line saying that the data is ready. Then the CPU will write the data present on the data bus to the register. The CPU either opens a path between the data bus and transistors controlling charge in and out of the register cells or opens a path directly between data bus and the register cells. It is otherwise impossible to "know" what to write into the register.

Comment: There isn't really a driver for the bus. The RAM will just answer to commands (asserted lines) on the DIMM's pins. Then it will output it's data onto the data bus without consideration for whatever the CPU was doing. It is the job of the CPU to receive the data properly. Basically to open an electrical path or let the voltage present onto the data bus create current (flow of charge) to either a transistor device controlling charge in out of the register or directly to the register.

Comment: No, there is no direct path. I have no idea where you're taking this from, but there simply isn't. Full stop. The energy stored in a RAM cell is really not high enough to make a difference on a wired bus. There *can't* be just a direct path. Please stop writing this nonsense.